# Representing Ranges of Time with Different Units in a Comparable Way

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, time

I have some Event objects that have a lifespan attribute.  I have varying types of events, each with different lifespans and potentially different units (e.g. 4-10 hours, 5-8 weeks, 1 month - 2 years).  I want to store these ranges as a uniform and comparable datatype but I'm not sure what my best option is.  Ideally I want to be able to go through a list of Events and find all that can last for 3 hours, 1 week, 2 months, etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is comparing values that are the same "substance" (i.e., time) yet have different units. This would be a great candidate for a [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). Value objects are not a common pattern in JavaScript, but they are no less applicable and are a great place for domain logic.  [This article](http://journal.crushlovely.com/post/88286828068/7-patterns-to-refactor-javascript-applications) is a great look at using value objects with JavaScript.

- Create a "class" by defining a JavaScript function.
- In it, store a value for lifespan in the smallest units that you use (hours).
- Create several internal methods that will get and set this value based on the unit type (for example, multiplying weeks by 168 to get number of hours). You may want to round to the nearest week/month/year when getting in those units.
- Create methods to compare the value in hours with the value in hours of another instance.

This will allow you to compare events independently of storing the unit of time that their lifespan is.